# WPF Can Text be Overlayed/Underlayed with a Thumb?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I've got a WPF UserControl that works as a floating "chat window" for an application I'm writing. Basically, three rows in a grid: header, richtextbox for the chat messages, and finally a textbox for user input.

The header element has a Thumb on it so that the user can drag the chat window around inside the application. But I also need to add text to that header. When I do this, of course, the Thumb becomes non-responsive because some other element is over the top of it. I can't figure out quite how to make this work, because the Thumb doesn't accept content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nesting the Thumb inside the HeaderContentControl, I make them separate, and set the IsHitTestVisible on the HeaderContentControl to false.